# I have Magento 1.9.4.4, can I use php 7.1 and no specific patch except those required for security

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7.1

Is Magento 1.9.4.4 compatible with php 7.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using it with php 7.2 currently without any additional patches.